# URL Setting Issue

Tags: php, url

I am learning PHP to working with BackEnd. I have made a website with MVC framework in PHP. Now I can visit my site with domain.com/public. I want to remove public keyword from URL. I have tried to put index.php and .htaccess file but it is showing me a 500 Server Error.

My index.php code for public:

```
<?php 
session_start();

require "../app/init.php";

$app = new App();
```

My .htaccess snippet:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Badly need the solution. Please leave me a way to make it. I searched on google but nothing found. Thank you

Comment: You should make `/public` the root directory not hide the request URI. You'd do that in either your nginx configuration or your Apache2 configuration.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Usually, an error 500 goes along with more details written to your server's error log

Comment: @Jaquarh thanks for your reply. I am using localhost to develop and hosting it in a shared hosting. I didn't find any article or something related to do it. Can you please share me some articles.

Comment: @NicoHaase Hello, I got some articles where it shown that moving index.php and htaccess file to root directory from /public directory and removing double dot from `require "../app/init.php";` this line can solve the issue.  But I got an 500 error by doing it. Without doing that everything is going right with domain.com/public URL.

Comment: 'hosting it in shared hosting' really does not help. All you're telling me there is you don't know if you're server admin or not. If you're, just update your Apache2 configuration to point at the `/public` directory. Whatever `sites-enabled` you have, change...

Comment: What does your server's error log tell you about that error? Why not use a higher error reporting level, such that the error is directly displayed on accessing the page - this helps to debug the issue